In JS, checking if element.style.bottom is empty not working
I have an element <div class="my-thing"></div>
I need to programmatically toggle the bottom property in javascript, so I have a simple click event that calls a function with this if statement:
if(element.style.bottom === "") {
   //do something
}

if( element.style.bottom !== "") {
   //do something else
}


However both of these if statements trigger at the same time if I don't have style set on my div. If I /do/ set style like style="bottom: 120px;" then the second statement gets triggered.
When it's empty I need only the first if statement to trigger, not both.
I tried changing === "" to === null or === undefined or all 3 separated by ||, and the same thing still happens. I also tried !element.style.bottom. None worked.
When I do console.log(element.style.bottom) when it's empty, I get <empty string> as a response in the console.
So how do I target a non-set property???

element.style only contains inline styles, not styles inherited from CSS. Use getComputedStyle() to get the actual style.

Does // do something assign to element.style.bottom? If it does, the second condition will succeed as well. Use else if for mutually exclusive conditions. Or just use else when the second condition is the exact opposite of the first one.

It will always be an inline style because the style is set by Javascript, so it should work right??? why isn't it working

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

If you haven't changed element.style.bottom between the two if statements, I don't see how they can both succeed.

Oh my gosh you were right it was the if/else if issue!!! ugh thanks so much!!

Why would the value be empty? By default they are set to...
bottom : auto
top : auto
right : auto
left : auto

And if you try to set them with any of these…
 === ""  === null  === undefined

Such values won’t be accepted and they will be reset to the default “auto”.
You can however use any of these values...
"unset", "initial", "inherit", "revert"

Changing your statement to...
if(element.style.bottom =='unset') {
   //do something
}

Or whichever one you've set it to.
